# implicit declaration of function NSMinX

Tags: iphone, ipad

The error "implicit declaration of function NSMinX "comes in my project?

Answer (score 7):

`NSMinX` is available on MacOS to get the least x coordinate for a given rectangle. Check if you (or some 3rd party lib) uses it.

iOS analogue for that function is `CGRectGetMinX`.